# Using AmpScript to update All Subscriber List

Tags: ampscript, soap-api, list, update, cloudpage

Here is my code that executes after a submit button is pressed on a cloudpage

```
%%[UpsertData("SubscribersTester", 1, "Email Address", @subKey, "First Name", @Fname, "Last Name", @Lname, 
     "Monthly", @Monthly, "Weekly", @Weekly, "Volunteer", @Volunteer, "Account Status", @Status, "Date Modified", NOW()) ]%%

  %%[SET @updateSub = CreateObject("Subscriber")]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@updateSub,"Email Address", @subKey)]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@updateSub,"Subscriber Key", @subKey)]%%
  %%[SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @memberID)]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@updateSub, "Client", @client)]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@updateSub,"Status","Active")]%%
  %%[SET @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")]%%
  %%[SET @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")]%%
  %%[SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions,"PropertyName","Status")]%%
  %%[AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions,"SaveOptions", @saveOptions)]%%
  %%[SET @updateObj = InvokeUpdate(@updateSub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions) ]%%
```

When it runs it hits me with a 500. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be showing the entire code but you have not defined the variable for `@subkey` or `@memberId`.  See the example here for using [AMPscript on a custom preference page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm).

```
%%[

  /* Get the Id of the account */
  Set @mid = [memberid]
  /* Get the key from the form */
  Set @subKey = [_subscriberkey]

  if Empty(@subKey) or  @subKey == "" then
   SET @subKey = "subkey@example.com"
  endif

]%%
```

Comment: Yes I have those variables already initialized way up at the top of the page. But is the 500 code always just a non existent variable being called?

Comment: Not always. It could a lot of things.

Comment: Is there a problem with how the calls are constructed though? The whole page is 300+ lines of code and that would be way too much to ask people go through for me.

Comment: You may have to troubleshoot it line by line. It could be the UpsertData -- data columns could have the wrong data types or wrong column names being used. 
Also you don't need to wrap every line in a `%%[ ]%%`. Put the entire code in the block. Start off with AMPscript 101 and move your way up: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript101.htm

Comment: Do the columns have to be in the same order from as the list?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Okay I added explicit statements initializing updateObj, updateSub, updateStatusMessage, updateErrorCode, updateOptions, and I took the spaces out of EmailAddress and SubscriberKey even if there was a space in the list header columns and that has seemed to work.

This would have helped me:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5

But I'm just glad I can do this without actually having to use SOAP API calls which I have no idea how to use